# jquery: is it possible to catch "expose" event of some image?

Tags: jquery, html

I have many images inside a webpage, and I want to only load it when the image is visible on the webpage, is it doable using jquery?

Eg) When the image is visible a function is called to get the image from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [**JAIL**](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail) plugin:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').jail(); // done
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function:

For example, consider a page with a simple image:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />
```

The event handler can be bound to the image:

```
$('#book').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

As soon as the image has been loaded, the handler is called.